# Ada How to Get Input Character by Character

Tags: string, ada

I am New to Ada and I am attempting to convert the code in a compiler tutorial on Recursive Decent Parser to Ada. Porting the tutorial, "Let's Build a Compiler" by Jack W Crenshaw has been a favorite way for me to learn many languages. I had everything working up to Chapter three, using single character tokens. The move to multi-character tokens has been troublesome.

I have code something like this sudo code:

```
procedure GetName is
  token: Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
begin
  while IsAlNum(Look) loop
    Token := Token & Look;
    GetChar;
  end loop
end GetName;
```

Now I know Ada intended for strings to be static. But I need to be able to concatenate each new character taken from the input to the collection of characters in Token. Look is the global look-ahead value (the last character inputted).

Thanks for you help. Also, are there any good Ada tutorials or recipes sites on the net? I've read Lovelace and Ada for C programmers. The Ada RMs are a bit formal and only show specifications not use...

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of this question, it looks like you are asking for help in Ada string processing.

Yes, Ada strings are indeed best handled as static strings, rather than resizable buffers. There are three typcial ways to deal with this.

The first is to make a really big `String` buffer, with a separate `Natural` variable to hold the logical length of the string. This is kind of a pain, and is somewhat error prone, but is at least faster than C's method of constantly scanning for a null at the end of the buffer.

The second is to just punt and use Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String. This is what most folks do, as it is easiest if you are used to thinking of things in a procedural way.

The third, (which I prefer when possible) is to handle your strings *functionally*. The main insight you need here is that Ada `String`s are indeed static, but you can control their lifetime, and you can dynamically make static strings whenever you want, if you program functionally.

For instance, I can create a new `Token` string of whatever length I want (with theoretically infinite lookahead) by doing something like the following:

```
function Matches_Token (Scanned : String) return boolean;  --// Returns true if the given string is a token
function Could_Match_Longer (Scanned : String) return boolean; --// Returns true if the given string could be part of a larger token.
function Get_Next_Char return Character;  --// Returns the next character from the stream
procedure Unget; --// Puts the last character back onto the stream
procedure Advance (Amount : Natural); --// Advance the stream pointer the given amount
function Longest_Matching_Token (Scanned : String) return String is
    New_Token : constant String := Scanned & Get_Next_Char;
begin
    --// Find the longest token a further scan can match
    if Could_Match_Longer(New_Token) then
        declare 
            LMT : constant String := Longest_Matching_Token (New_Token);
        begin
            if LMT /= "" then
                unget;
                return LMT;
            end if;
        end;
    end if;

    --// See if this string at least matches.
    if Matches_Token(New_Token) then
        unget;
        return New_Token;
    else
        unget;
        return "";
    end if;
end Build_Token;

function Get_Next_Token return String is
    Next_Token : constant String := Build_Token("");
begin
    Advance (Next_Token'length);
    return Next_Token;
end Get_Next_Token;
```

This isn't always the most efficient method of string handling (too much stack usage), but it is often the easiest.

In practice, scanning and parsing is actually kind of a special-case application, where ugly things one typically avoids, like buffers (method 1) and gotos, are often advisable.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the info. Porting this compiler has long been one of my favorite ways to learn a new language. It seems to bring up many issues that usually don't arise in simpler applications. It also gives me a good bench mark for working with a language. The compiler in the tutorial is meant for a 68K machine but I have in the past successfully converted it to 8051, 6811, 8086 and even C for use as a cross compiler. Right now I am trying to learn Ada and have only  a hand full of hours actually working with it. I have found information difficult to find.

Comment: @user693336 - Certianly the best way I've found to learn languages is to try to program something in them. This issue with Strings is they are the first thing any Ada learner tries to play with, and the Ada array rules have subtle (but far-reaching) implications. Unless you are used to functional languages, the first approach is typically to try to use C string handling methods, which always leads to massive frustration (unless you give up and use `Ada.Strings.Unbounded`). Kind of unfortunate that Ada's oddest nit is the very first thing most noobs try to do, but there it is.

Answer (score 3):

The single character "get" method for Ada is [Ada.Text_IO.Get](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-10-1.html#I5737). Also in that section of the Text_IO package are the Look_Ahead and Get_Immediate procedures.

A good source for lots of worked out Ada examples is Rosetta Code's [Ada Category](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category%3aAda).

Comment: I can already get a single character. My issue is in modifying the existing code to accept multi character input and tokens. I am currently using Ada.Text_IO.Get which works fine for single characters. I have found that making the change from single character tokens to multi-character tokens in Ada requires a lot of work where in C/C++, Pascal, PHP, Python, ... it was an easy move. But Ada's strict type checking means the change propagates throughout the code. But I guess that's the point of this exercise, to learn about a new language.

Comment: @user693336 - This is a pretty basic thing about Ada (that often frustrates C users). You can still "hack" in Ada, but the strong type system forces you to stop and *redesign* things properly when you make fundamental object role changes. This is actually one of the best things about the language.

Comment: Just looked at OpenToken. I'm going to have to play with this once I get a few weeks of Ada under my belt! It sounds great!!!

Answer (score 3):

If you're going with Ada 2005 or later (Actually 95 might have it, not entirely sure), you can use Streams. Something like this:

```
With Ada.Text_IO;

With
Ada.Streams.Stream_IO,
Ada.Text_IO.Text_Streams,
Ada.IO_Exceptions;


Procedure IO is
    Use Ada.Text_IO;

    -- Get the Standard_Input.
    Input_File : Ada.Text_IO.File_Type:= Ada.Text_IO.Standard_Input;

    -- Create a stream from the Standard Input.
    Input_Stream : Access Ada.Streams.Root_Stream_Type'Class:=
      Ada.Text_IO.Text_Streams.Stream( File => Input_File );

Begin

    GET_USER_INPUT:
    declare
    C: Character;
    begin
    loop
        Character'Read( Input_Stream, C );
        exit when C = '*';
        -- Build your string here.
    end loop;
    -- THIS IS AN ALTERNATE WAY FOR EXITING THE ABOVE LOOP.
    Exception
    When ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.END_ERROR => Null; -- Raised normally at EOF.
    end GET_USER_INPUT;
    -- Suggested, refactoring GET_USER_INPUT into a function.

    Put_Line( "Testing." );

End IO;
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found that changing my thinking a bit and defining a character array and forcing a limit on the input length gave me a working solution. However, the use of the character array caused issue down the road in other procedures. Ada is so different from C/C++ in that it forces types and data size.

Comment: I know; I actually like it -- sure, it can be a little challenging at times, but it also ensures that I'm not going to be likely to have to debug the program of mysterious & intermittent failures.

Comment: As the person who originally wrote OpenToken (the Ada compiler construction toolkit), I second the use of stream input rather than Text_IO for ease-of-use. However, if you want to actually *use* this compiler of yours, you may find it helpful to write a little package/class to read as much of the file into RAM as possible, and then get characters from that buffer thereafter. The less I/O's you do, the better.

Comment: The intent here is not to build the compiler for actual use. I haven't used a 68K in anything for many years now... The intent is to try and replicate the original compiler structure outline by Jack so that I can both learn Ada and compare it to other implementations in other languages. Over the past few years I written this same compiler in PHP, Python, Perl, Free Pascal C, C++, Scheme, Java, Gambas and other languages. So It just needs to work but not as a production compiler. I'd use Flex/Bison for a real compiler. Hey, is there an Ada version of Flex/Bison?

Comment: At http://www.ics.uci.edu/~self/ you can see three links for Aflex and Ayacc; there's also supposed to be Flex/Yacc under GWenerator at http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnavi/ -- Dmitri has a parser-package here: http://www.dmitry-kazakov.de/ada/components.htm#Parsers_etc -- and last is OpenToken over here: http://www.stephe-leake.org/ada/opentoken.html

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a function to concatenate each new character taken from the input an return it all as a string. It may be adaptable to do what you need.

```
FUNCTION get_a_string ( ch : IN Character ) RETURN String IS
-----------------------------------------------------------------
--| Recursively hack out a string from a stream of single
--| character input. Starting with an ESC sentinel and ending
--| with an EOL sentinel.
--| ESC is the ESC character and EOL is a space.
----------------------------------------------------------------
    next : Character;
    ch2s : String(1..1);
BEGIN -- get_a_string
    Ada.Text_IO.Put( "Waiting: ");--BARF
    Ada.Text_IO.Get( Item => next );

    IF ch = ESC THEN -- start
       RETURN get_a_string(next);
    ELSIF next = EOL THEN --Escape Case
       ch2s(1) := ch;
       RETURN ch2s;
    ELSE -- Keep getting input
       RETURN ch & get_a_string(next);
    END IF;
END get_a_string;
```

In case my Instructor or TA finds this as a match to the code I turned in. I wrote it, so I'm not cheating.